# modalpopupextender progress bar does not work in asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have followed the ModalPopupExtender progress bar shown [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/guillermo/archive/2008/02/24/ajax-how-to-create-a-quot-processing-quot-modal-window-using-updateprogress-and-modalpopup-asp-net-ajax-controls.aspx)

the rpogressbar seem to be work fine in asp.net website project but not in asp.net web application project.

did any one face the similar issue? if so is there any solution or work around for it?

Comment: Umm... That's not related to ASP.NET **MVC**, re-tagging would be in order.